# Whats the Use of Gauge Control in Rdlc Report?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have seen a new control named Gauge in winform RDLC report.

Whats the use this Control. Where can we use it?.

And How Can we Use?.

Please Explain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gauges are not meant for RDLC. It is for server side reports (rdl)

This might help http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207041.aspx

Comment: Are You Sure this is only for RDl Report?. Bzs I am only know RDLC. I saw this Gauges in Tool Box. Thats Why i asked here. Thanks.